Switchport command to find out what ports aren't active on a switch
I know that sho int | inc connected shows connected ports. What do you use to find ports that aren't connected?

Instead of connected, use notconnect.
The show interface status command gives it all to you, and you are using the include to filter the output. Without the filter, you get something like:
Port      Name               Status       Vlan       Duplex  Speed Type 
Gi1/1     Cisco Wireless AP' disabled     trunk        auto   auto 10/100/1000-TX
Gi1/2     Cisco Wireless AP' disabled     trunk        auto   auto 10/100/1000-TX
Gi1/3     Cisco Wireless AP' disabled     trunk        auto   auto 10/100/1000-TX
Gi1/4     Standard IP Phone  notconnect   4            auto   auto 10/100/1000-TX
Gi1/5     Standard IP Phone  connected    4          a-full a-1000 10/100/1000-TX

If you change the include to disabled you can see only the disabled interfaces. You can filter however you like.

hi and thanks. Yeah I know that command but was hoping there was a way to show like the connected ports and just show the not connected ones. Thanks for your input.

Actually, its right there in your response so thank you. I was using not connected and it's only notconnect. That gives me what I need. You are a blessing and thanks!!! I now have what I needed!!

@DanaLivernois, if it answered your question, please accept the answer so that it does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Hi Ron. I'm new here where do I accept it?

You got it. When you get the reputation, you can vote up and down, too.
